# Flatten a Map of Option to Map

Tags: scala

I have a `Map[A, Option[B]]`, what is the optimal way to make a flatten to get a `Map[A, B]` ?

I know for a list we can use flatten, but this structure is different

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, they are not the same, so you will need a way to define what happens if a value is None. I assume you want to ignore those keys, if so, you can collect with a partial function:

```
map.collect {
  case (k, Some(v)) => k -> v
}
```

or use a for-comprehension

```
  for ((k, Some(v)) <- map) yield k -> v
```

Comment: yes I did not precise that I don't want key with None value, thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: actually `for ((k, Some(v)) <- map ) yield k -> v` is enough

Comment: very true! I'll update! Did that pattern match above and not below, idiot...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind double-iteration:

```
map.filter(_._2.nonEmpty).mapValues(_.get)
```

Example:

```
scala> Map(1 -> Some(1), 2 -> None).filter(_._2.nonEmpty).mapValues(_.get)
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)
```

---

Or using this implicit:

```
implicit def flat[K,V](kv: (K, Option[V])) = kv._2.map(kv._1 -> _).toList
```

Then:

```
map.flatten.toMap
```

Or without using (potentially unsafe) implicit:

```
map flatMap flat
```

Example:

```
scala> Map(1 -> Some(1), 2 -> None).flatten.toMap
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)

scala> def flat[K,V](kv: (K, Option[V])) = kv._2.map(kv._1 -> _).toList 
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
flat: [K, V](kv: (K, Option[V]))List[(K, V)]

scala> Map(1 -> Option(1), 2 -> None).flatMap(flat)
res29: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1)
```

Comment: Worth noting that `mapValues` returns a view on the map, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @jhn depends, if code inside mapValues is referential-transparent like in my answer, why should anyone care? For Java-serialization (if one's still using it for some reason), there is always .view.force or .map(identity)

Comment: Why should anyone care? Performance.

Comment: @jhn first, "If you don't mind double-iteration" means "if you don't care about performance much". Second, view actually improves performance for large collections as it doesn't create intermidiate collection (so less GC), that's why `mapValues` creates a view actually. Of course, `get` is gonna be called every time view is used, but performance loses here are questionable (it's still linear - anything else depends on concrete situation). More than that, there is no specific performance requirements in the question - "optimal" doesn't mean "performance efficient".

Comment: @jhn and, as it said, you can always `view.force` if you really really find serious performance leak because of every-time `get`, which in most cases I doubt (as it doesn't change asymptotic complexity). It's not "optimal" to chase after let's say 1% performance improvement sacrificing your code readability. Anyway only performance test (for real OP's case) can definetly say wether or not you shoud use views